# Dynamic picture path - Vue, Webpack, assets - unexpected require

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I want to display a picture from assets folder based on some property value. I have created a method with a switch. The picture was not found. After some googling I realized that this is caused by webpack and I shall use `require`. But I still encounter strange errors.

This works:

```
<img src="@/assets/happy.png" class="pr-2" align="middle">
```

Dynamic:

```
<img :src="this.votedPicture" class="pr-2" align="middle">

votedPicture() {
  switch (this.$store.getters.POLL.my_vote) {
    case 'neutral':
      return require('@/assets/happy.png');
    default:
      return require('@/assets/angry.png');
  }
},
```

},

This fails with `Unexpected require()`.

When I move the `require` to `img`:

```
<img :src="require(this.votedPicture)" class="pr-2" align="middle">
```

there is an error in console:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js:1888 Error: Cannot find module '@/assets/happy.png'
at webpackEmptyContext (organisms sync:2)
at Proxy.render (CompletePoll.vue?4b27:31)
at VueComponent.Vue._render (vue.runtime.esm.js:3548)
```

So what is the proper way?

Comment: Have you tried referencing the image from your public folder?

Comment: According to documentation this is not recommended

Comment: Your images wont be processed by webpack.. You will store the images in the public folder right? So when you build your project, the files will be moved over to your dist folder

Comment: It should be `:src="votedPicture"`, no `this` prefix required

Comment: _"This fails with Unexpected require()"_  What **exactly** is the error message here and where do you see it?

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you're seeing ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-jones-94i3b?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors   Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
error: Unexpected require() (global-require)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just an Eslint rule. It fails because of eslint-plugin from vue-cli I guess.
Try creating an .eslintrc file containing

```
{
  rules: {
    "global-require": 0  
  }
}
```

Comment: I turned it off for the current line and it works now: // eslint-disable-next-line global-require